# C++ use templates to avoid compiler from checking a boolean

Tags: c++, templates, boolean

Let's say I have a function:

```
template <bool stuff>
inline void doSomething() {
    if(stuff) {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
doSomething<true>();
doSomething<false>();
```

It would pring out:

```
Hello
Goodbye
```

What I'm really wondering is does the compiler fully optimize this?
When I call the templated function with true, will it create a function that just outputs "Hello" and avoids the if statement and the code for "Goodbye"?

This would be really useful for this one giant function I just wrote that's supposed to be very optimized and avoid as many unnecessary if statement checks as possible.  I have a very good feeling it would, at least in a release build with optimizations if not in a debug build with no optimizations.

Comment: When it comes to optimizations, you **don't** follow your gut feeling. If you do, you're screwed because you *will* be misguided. How hard can it be to look at the produced code?

Comment: @ablm Only if you only want one implementation for a given build. As soon as the choice depends on the caller (and that seems likely here), it becomes extremely ugly.

Comment: ... and offers no benefits over the template version.

Comment: @ablm The only reference to different builds is at the end, where he speculates on the optimizations the compiler might do with the template version.

Comment: @ablm Actually I don't really mind if the debug build is also optimized.

This is really also just a question about how templates work and not necessarily about how I should best handle optimizing code.

Comment: As a "general" case (YMMV), I would expect the debug build to generate code for the "if" statement. I have never seen an inkling of dead code on the MSVC or gcc compiler, and i am using this pattern rather heavily.

Answer (score 17):

Disclaimer: Noone can guarantee anything.

That said, this an obvious and easy optimization for any compiler. It's quite safe to say that it will be optimized away, unless the optimizer is, well,  practically useless.

Since your "true" and "false" are constants, you are unambiguously creating an obvious dead branch in each class, and the compiler should optimize it away. Should is taken literally here - I would consider it a major, major problem if an "optimising" compiler did not do dead branch removal.

In other words, if your compiler cannot optimize this, it is the use of that compiler that should be evaluated, not the code.

So, I would say your gut feeling is correct: while yes, no "guarantees" as such can be made on each and every compiler, I would not use a compiler incapable of performing simplistic optimizations in any production environment, and of course not in any performance critical one. (In release builds of course).

**So, use it. Any modern optimizing compiler will optimize it away because it is a trivial optimization. If in doubt, check disassembly, and if it is not optimized, change the compiler to something more modern.**

In general, if you are writing any kind of performance-critical code, you must rely, at least to some extent, on compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

This is inherently up to the compiler, so you'd have to check the compiler's documentation or the generated code. But in simple cases like this, you can easily implement the optimization yourself:

```
template <bool stuff>
inline void doSomething();

template<>
inline void doSomething<true>() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

template<>
inline void doSomething<false>() {
    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
}
```

But "optimization" isn't really the right word to use since this might actually degrade performance. It's only an optimization if it actually benefits your code performance.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it really createa two functions, but

> premature optimization is the root of all evil

especially if your changing your code structure because of a simple if statement. I doubt that this will affect performance. Also the boolean must be static, that means you cant take a runtime evaluated var and pass it to the function. How should the linker know which function to call? In this case youll have to manually evaluate it and call the appropiate function on your own.

Comment: I do agree with premature optimization not being a good thing, but this is just something really trivial and I know for a fact avoiding these if statements will definitely reduce some instructions.  I'm doing this algorithm basically 60 times a second for a 3D renderer.

I guess it could increase the executable size and use more memory/affect the cache/whatever other obscure things I might be affecting so I could try both ways.

Comment: @Iseletsky What i wanted to tell you, is that instead of optimizing some little ifs you should optimize the rendering itself. A small if has even no impact if you iterate 60 times a second.vMaybe if you would iterate 10.000.000 times you could feel a small impact but often also in this case things like math calcs (pow, sqr etc.) cost much much more time. Beside that, even AAA games have a fairly abstract OOP structure. I think you should be more concerned of how you store your vericies instead of trying to elimate some ifs.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are really good at constant folding. That is, in this case it would surprise me if the check would stay until after optimization. A non-optimized build might still have the check. The easiest way to verify is to create assembler output and check.

That said, it is worth noting that the compiler has to check both branches for correctness, even if it only ever uses one branch. This frequently shows up, e.g., when using slightly different algorithms for Random Access Iterators and other iterators. The condition would depend on a type-trait and one of the branches may fail to compile depending on operations tested for by the traits. The committee has discussed turning off this checking under the term *static if* although there is no consensus, yet, on how the features would look exactly (if it gets added).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want (in essence) end up with 'two' functions that are optimised for either a true or a false input so that they don't need check that flag?

Aside from any trivial optimisation that may yield (I'm against premature otimisation - I believe in maintainability before measurement before optimisation), I would say why not refactor your function to actually be two functions? If they have common code then then that code could be refactored out too. However if the requirement is such that the refactoring is non optimal then I'd replace that with a #define refactoring.

Comment: The code is way too hard to refactor so that there are 2 functions.

The 2 functions are identical, except there is this one inner if statement deep inside that just needs to either do something one way or another.

And it needs to do the check again in another part of the code and do it there if it didn't do it in the other part.

This is a very specific function that will only be used in one place anyway.  Rather than have massive code duplication I was thinking of a way to just make it 1 function call but still be as optimized for speed as possible. (3D rasterization of a view frustum)

Comment: The #define wouldn't work since I'm calling it like this

doSomething<true>();
doSomething<false();

One after the other.